# Want to read user input and call method in a second class

Tags: java

Hello again StackOverflow,

**Short Version:
If I have a string called secondCommand, and that string is a method I want to call in another class, how can I use that string in the format:
"Circle.secondCommand"
to actually call that method?**

Long Version:
I'm writing a program about shape manipulation - I'm using only Circle at the moment but I will expand to using 3 more shapes once I have Circle working properly. My program at the moment works like so:

An InputReader scans the user input, returning each word input separately. This is processed in my ShapeProgrammer class in a method called 'Execute'. That method as it stands is such:

```
private void execute(String[] commands)
{
    String firstCommand = commands[0];
    String secondCommand = commands[1];
    String thirdCommand = commands[2];
    {
        Circle c = shapes.get(firstCommand);
        if(firstCommand.equals("circle")) {
        makeACircle(commands);
        }
        else if(c != null){
            int newInt = Integer.parseInt(thirdCommand);
            if (newInt != null)
                Circle.secondCommand(newInt);              
            c = null;
        }
        else if(firstCommand.equals("help")) {
        printHelp();
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Unknown command: " + firstCommand);
        }
    }
}
```

String[] commands is defined in a while statement in an earlier method like so:

```
String[] commands = reader.getInput();
```

I have all the methods for the shape itself in separate classes for each shape - I have written into the Execute method what I was trying to do, but NetBeans is giving me all kinds of errors.

Users will be expected (and) told to input their commands in a particular format:

When creating the shape, it will be **shape name**

Each shape is stored in a HashMap at the moment where the string is the name

When wanting to edit/use the shape, it will be **name command variable** - I think I've got as far as calling the shape from the HashMap, now I'm just wondering how I can make my string secondCommand useable so as to call the method from the other class.

As a sidenote, I have the
    int newInt = Integer.parseInt(thirdCommand)
as some of my methods are for changeSize or otherwise require an int input. I could get rid of that and put it into the Circle class if that would be easier, I'd then only have to call the thirdCommand string into the other methods and convert to an int there.

Comment: It's so long make it precise and ask a particular question.

Answer (score 0):

I think [reflections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) may help you. It is an easy way to call methods by name. This [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/methods.html) can help you. Basically:

```
        String methodName = ***;
    Class classToBeInvoked = **.class;

    Method javaMethod = classToBeInvoked.getMethod(methodName, <arguments-type>);
    Object returnType = javaMethod.invoke(classToBeInvoked, <arguments>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (not so elegant like reflection) way to solve it,

Why don't you define all of these methods in an String arrayand use it in a switch-case block?

```
////////// In your end method ////////
switch (secondCommand) {
    case "DIAGON":
        Circle.diagon();
        break;

    case "THING":
        Circle.thing();
        break;

    case "ANOTHERFORMULA":
        Circle.anotherFormula();
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Daamn good.");
        break;
}
```

Use the method names like this if you don't wanna be a hero, and you'll be good.